# I'm receiving an 'Illegal byte sequence' error when cloning from a mercurial repository

Tags: macos, version-control, mercurial

I'm trying to clone a project from a mercurial repository on a mac, and while the project starts to clone, loading bar and all, at some point the process sputters out with this error message:

```
abort: Illegal byte sequence: <a_specific_file_in_the_repository>
```

I am running a macOS High Sierra, version 10.13.6. And I have reinstalled mercurial, so that I'm running Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 5.5).

Can anybody else who has run into this issue provided some assistance?

Comment: Is that file named with invalid UTF-8?  macOS cannot write files to APFS if their file names aren't valid UTF-8.

Comment: Can you say what the filename is? It sounds like it might be this bug - https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5762

Comment: abort: Illegal byte sequence: '/Users/user1/sa-public/library/articles/the_secrets_of_the_audition_process_the?temple_of_audition_doom.html'

Comment: Well, moving the html from that file into a new file seemed to work, so perhaps there was some corruption in the file.